# Is it possible that I see the file result of unitest project after running it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

Hello I am new to programming. Is it possible for me to see the result of a unit test somewhere. I want to see how my code works by giving different inputs to the unit test according to the code below, but I do not know how I can see the results. Does this 2 line of code give the inputs to `ExperimentPotentialRadius` method? Where is the output file? Is right clicking on this unit test method enough to execute it?

```
[DataRow(@"Testfiles\digit9.png", 32, 64, new int[] { 4, 8, 12, 16 })]
[DataRow(@"Testfiles\digit8.png", 64, 64, new int[] { 4, 8, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32 })]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can improve your question by (1) posting code as formatted text instead of an image and (2) asking one specific question (rather than a bunch of rambling questions as you have done here). You are more likely to get a good response if you ask a good question!

Comment: I assume this is mstest? You can read about the `DataRow` attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute?view=mstest-net-1.3.2). So yes, those two lines of code provide the inputs for your test.

Comment: Could you share all ‘ExperimentPotentialRadius’ method code here? It will help others make a test.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a unit test is a boolean state: failed or succeeded (also known as "red and green") determined through assertions.

If the code, that is run in your test writes any files, then you either need to assert on the content of the file or the methods called for writing (via mocks) or you need to inspect the files manually afterwards (which defeats the purpose of an automated test).

Where are the output files? Well, that depends on where your code is writing them. There is not special folder for files written during test runs.